# HTML li not aligning text properly

Tags: html, html-lists

This is a weird issue am facing currently on my clients site. Am using li to list all the steps of a recipes but the steps that has long paragraph, its falls down. When it falls down its not aligned as it should be. See image for more information.

Sorry, my English is very bad.

[image]

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS here.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: It looks like you are adding the `&bull;` into the text instead of using `list-style:disc;`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul {list-style-position:outside;}
```